# How can I use unicode characters as identifiers in PostScript? Is it impossible?

Tags: pstricks, unicode, postscript

I feel "uncomfortable" with the existing constants below (which are already defined in PSTricks)

```
Euler = 2.718281828
Pi = 3.141592654
```

because I think using `e` and `π` is much more natural.

My question is : How can I use unicode characters as identifiers in PostScript? Is it impossible?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\pstVerb
{
    /e {2.718281828} def 
    /π {3.141592654} def 
}

\def\f{ln(e^x)+π}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](0,-2)(5,5)
    \psplot{0}{4}{\f}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no, you can't do this. According to page 25 of the [Postscript Language Reference Manual](https://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf)

> There are three encodings for the PostScript language: ASCII, binary
>   token, and binary object sequence.

Comment: Sorry, Is π (ALT+227) ASCII?

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch --- [I don't think so](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: @Pleasedon'ttouch Alt 247 is presumably some input convention in your system but pi is unicode U+03C0 (decimal 960) which isn't in the 0-127 ASCII range.